# Allow code to stop processing and wait for user input

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am creating a wpf app using menuitems and grids.  I have a vertical menu and when each item is clicked I display a grid with textboxes, buttons, etc.  When the users enters info in one of the grids and hits the Submit button I want to to display another grid to get more information depending on the entered file type.  I can't figure out how to have the code transfer processing to this grid code to collect the additional data and then return to where the other processing was and use the additional information.  I am not sure if this approach is even the best way to go.

Comment: Just use WPF's built-it `PageFunction<T>`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478(v=vs.100).aspx#Structured_Navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about multiple pages on wpf, here are some resources you can use to help you achieve that.     [Wpf multiple pages](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22927/Multiple-Window-Interface-for-WPF)

Comment: I'm not sure OP is talking about MDI

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I will look into the multiple pages route.  Does anyone have a simple example I could use to get started?